# Having problems creating dependent drop downs using django and jquery

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

So I found [this](http://blog.devinterface.com/2011/02/how-to-implement-two-dropdowns-dependent-on-each-other-using-django-and-jquery/) about how to make two dependent drop downs. I followed the example, and now when I try and load the page with the drop down menus, I get this error:

```
AttributeError at /brewkeep/beers/
'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

This is the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.1.111:8080/brewkeep/beers/

Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'brewkeep',
 'django.contrib.admin')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/di/djangostack-1.4-1/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  188.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/home/di/djangostack-1.4-1/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_response
  94.         if response.status_code == 404:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /brewkeep/beers/
Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

This is my code:

**urls.py**

```
(r'^brewkeep/beers/$', 'brewkeep.templatetags.brewery_beer_select'),
(r'^brewkeep/beers/(?P<brewery_id>[-\w]+)/all_json_models/$', 'brewkeep.views.beer_views.show_beers'),
```

**models.py**

```
class Brewery(models.Model):
    idbrewery = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=765)
class Beer(models.Model):
    idbeer = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    brewery = models.ForeignKey(Brewery, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

**templatetags.py**

```
from brewkeep.models import Brewery
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag("show_beers.html")
def brewery_beer_select(request):
    breweries = Brewery.objects.all().order_by('name')
    return {'breweries' : breweries}
```

**show_beers.html**

```
<form action="" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <p>Brewery:</p>
    <select name="brewery" id="brewery">
        <option value="">Select a brewery</option>
        {% for brewery in breweries %}
            <option value="{{brewery.idbrewery}}">{{brewery.name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}    
    </select>
    <select name="beer" id="beer" disabled="true">
        <option>Select a beer</option>
    </select>
</form>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(
        function() {
            $("select#brewery").change(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    $("select#beer").html("<option>Select a beer</option>");
                    $("select#beer").attr('disabled', true);
                }
                else {
                    var url = "/brewkeep/beers/" + $(this).val() + "/all_json_models";
                    var brewery = $(this).val();
                    $.getJSON(url, function(beers) {
                        var options = '<option value="">Select a beer</option>';
                        for (var i = 0; i < beers.length; i++) {
                            options += '<option value="' + beers[i].pk + '">' + beers[i].fields['description'] + '</option>';
                        }
                        $("select#beer").html(options);
                        $("select#beer option:first").attr('selected', 'selected');
                        $("select#beer").attr('disabled', false);
                    });
                }
            });


            $("select#beer").change(function(vent) {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
    );

</script>
```

**beer_views.py**

```
def show_beers(request, brewery_id):
    brewery_obj = Brewery.objects.get(idbrewery=brewery_id)
    beers = Beer.objects.all().filter(brewery=brewery_obj).order_by('name')
    json_models = serializers.serialize("json", beers)
    return HttpResponse(json_models, mimetype="application/javascript")
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by dependent dropdown? A select box whose values are determined by the input in another select box?

Comment: @NickBewley Yes. I have two drop downs. When I select one dropdown, I want the other dropdown to auto fill with certain things. Then when I select the 2nd drop down, I want the page to display certain things.

Answer (score 3):

To do what you ae asking for, I like to use [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects). It includes js functionality to chain your models with a modelfield called ChainedForeignKey. For example, if you wanted to have a Phone chained select, where a user could select a type of phone, make, and model (ex. Iphone 4 S, or Samsung Galaxy 2), it would look something like this:

models.py:

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

class Series(models.Model):
    series = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Model(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series)

class Make(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    model = models.ForeignKey('Model')

class Phone(models.Model):
     make = models.ForeignKey(Make)
     model = ChainedForeignKey(Model, chained_field='make', chained_model_field='make',)
     series = ChainedForeignKey(Series, chained_field='model', chained_model_field='model',)

class PhoneForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Phone
```

template.html:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

{% block content %}
  <form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type='submit' value='submit' />
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

---

EDIT: based on comment

From the docs

> The chained field is the field on the same model the field should be chained too.
>
> The chained model field is the field of the chained model that corresponds to the model linked too by the chained field.

Change to `chained_model_field='name'`.

Comment: So I tried using `django-smart-selects`. In my models, I changed my `Brewery` field in my `Beer` model to this: `brewery = ChainedForeignKey(Brewery, chained_field="brewery", chained_model_field="brewery")`. After I do that, when I go to my form, the drop down for the `Brewery` field doesn't populate.

Comment: Change the chained model field as described in the edit and see if that solves your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple template, `beers_select_options.html`, for the options in your beer select -

```
<option>Select a beer</option>
    {% for beer in beers %}
        <option value="{{ beer.idbeer }}">{{ beer }}</option>
    {% enfor %}
```

serve it up with a view

```
def ajax_get_beers(request):
    idbrewery = int(request.POST['idbrewery'])
    brewery = Brewery.objects.get(idbrewery=idbrewery)
    beers = Beer.objects.filter(brewery=brewery)
    return render_to_response('beers_select.html', {'beers': beers})
```

Then attach a function to the change event on the brewery select box -

```
$('#brewery').change(function() {
    var idbrewery = $(this).find(':selected').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/your/ajax_get_beers/view',
        data: {'idbrewery': idbrewery}
        success: function(options_html) {
            $('#beer').html(options_html);
        }
    });
});
```

That would do it, except that you've probably got csrf protection, so you'll need to add the following before your javascript (see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax)) -

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
$.ajaxSetup({
    crossDomain: false, 
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

This requires the [jquery cookie plugin](https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js) (there's an alternative for getting the cookie in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax)).

I haven't tested my code, but I think it's all you really need (I guess you'll need an addition to your url conf for the ajax view).